# spring-boot 1.5 ConfigurationProperties with number in property not binding when using kebab case

Tags: spring-boot

Consider the following example class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("my.test")
public class MyTestConfiguration {

    private boolean follow3xxRedirects = true;

    public boolean isFollow3xxRedirects() {
        return follow3xxRedirects;
    }

    public void setFollow3xxRedirects(boolean follow3xxRedirects) {
        this.follow3xxRedirects = follow3xxRedirects;
    }
}
```

Setting the property `my.test.follow-3xx-redirects=false` does not correctly override the `follow3xxRedirects` property with `false` when using spring-boot 1.5.15 (although it works as expected in 2.0.4).

Oddly, if the above class is refactored as follows, the property binds just fine:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("my")
public class MyTestConfiguration {

    private final Test test = new Test();

    public Test getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public static class Test {
        private boolean follow3xxRedirects = true;

        public boolean isFollow3xxRedirects() {
            return follow3xxRedirects;
        }

        public void setFollow3xxRedirects(boolean follow3xxRedirects) {
            this.follow3xxRedirects = follow3xxRedirects;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the first example to work with kebab-case, or is this a bug in spring-boot 1.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a bug in Spring Boot 1.5 per se. But Spring Boot 2.0 Configuration Property Binding is completely over hauled.

Read the Configuration Property Binding section under [Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes) for more information

Comment: It feels buggy that in 1.5 this works just fine with a nested class, but not when the property is on the top level class.